# variable declaration in while loop

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

class Counter
{
    int val;

public:
    Counter() { val = 0; }
    int Next() { return ++val; }
};

int main()
{
    Counter counter;

    while (int c = counter.Next() <= 5)
    {
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}
```

When run, the program prints out `1` 5 times.  Thus, `.Next()` is returning the expected value as the while loop does terminate.

Why is the value of `c` remain set to the initial value?

I'm *very* new to C++ (this is the first C++ program I've written) and am just trying to understand how the return value of `.Next()` could be as expected and evaluated but not captured in the `c` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<=` operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `=` operator.

So, with

```
while (int c = counter.Next() <= 5)
```

The compiler interprets it as:

```
while (int c = (counter.Next() <= 5))
```

which assigns the result of the logical expression to `c`, which will be 1 while the expression holds true.

Try this instead:

```
int c;

while ((c = counter.Next()) <= 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a conversion operator for `Counter`, and remove the need to declare an extra variable.

```
class Counter {
    int val_;
public:
    Counter() : val_(0) {}
    int Next() { return ++val_; }
    operator int () const { return val_; }
};

//...
    Counter counter;
    while (counter.Next() <= 5) {
        cout << counter << endl;
    }
```